# Is there a way to manually render template in Polymer?

Tags: polymer

Polymer provides automatic two-way binding between template and data which is great. It also provides a one time binding. Is there a way to have a one-time binding with a way to refresh it later? I like the expressiveness of the polymer template, but I am not sure about performance of polling. (we have really complicated dom). We are investigating possibility of doing FRP (possibly Bacon.js) in Polymer.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

My reaction to questions like this is usually: have you actually observed a performance issues?

Keep in mind, if the browser supports `Object.observe()`, there's no polling. If that feature isn't available, Polymer does default to polling in order to flush the data-binding system and propagate changes. That doesn't necessarily mean DOM changes either. Polymer's data binding system makes the [minimal amount of DOM changes to reflect model changes](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/databinding-advanced.html#how-data-binding-works). See the section on maintaining instances as well.

Comment: We are rendering a large size table composed of many elements and when we tried to transpose it by transpose the view model backing the table, the performance really suffers. Polymer tried to re-render each element rather than re-render the whole table from scratch. There might be a work around. But I feel that we don't need the Object.observe if we are doing Functional Reactive programming where we have much better grasp of the data change event stream.

Comment: ebidel, thanks for trying to provide more concrete help. We could go down that route (diagnose the performance issue we are facing). But I think fundamentally what I want is to take some control of the observe-render cycle. State change is managed differently in reactive programming. Multiple observable event streams can be easily merged into one event stream, which means explicitly observing every objects isn't necessary anymore.  It's a different paradigm. What I really want to know is how to incorporate this paradigm to polymer.